# How to Use JMeter HTTP Authorization Manager effectively?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I am facing a specific problem.

Scenario: Any software or website where user need to provide user credentials (username & password).

My Test Plan:
I want to test the login page, So I have recorded the login procedure using Blazemeter. saved the plan and open it with JMeter. But my user credentials that I have provided weren't there in the HTTP Authorization Manager, So I have put them there manually (url, username, password). I have intentionally put incorrect password, but after run the test plan in view results tree listener it appears as successful run! Why? How?

Thanks for your patience.

I also tried to put http sampler request manually, and still same result.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) is not for "Any software or website where user need to provide user credentials", it's for handling of **very specific cases** when the system under test is protected by external authentication subsystems, in particular:

- [Basic access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- [Digest access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)
- [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM#:%7E:text=In%20a%20Windows%20network%2C%20NT,integrity%2C%20and%20confidentiality%20to%20users.)
- [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

If you record a web application which uses any of the above - JMeter will add the HTTP Authorization Manager. In latter 2 cases you will need to perform a little bit of configuration prior to recording or replaying, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Thank you, How should I configure it then? Like, If I want to load test "www.yts.mx" or some banking software how should I prepare my test plan for Login page?

Comment: If you want to parameterize your test normally people store credentials in [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and then add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) so each thread (virtual user) has its own credentials

Comment: I am sorry to brag about this problem for this long, But I have been looking for answer about this for a long time yet no luck. By the way I have configured CSV file and still same issue. I have inserted wrong password and still JMeter gives positive test run feedback.

Comment: It's a different question, you should ask it in a separate thread. I'll give you a hint however. JMeter treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, if you want to additionally check the server response - add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter)

Comment: I think my problem lies with your very first answer. I don't think the software I am trying to test is using Basic Authentication. Is there any way to know what kind of authentication is a software or website is using?